# Process builder scheduled action is removed from queue even when condition is true

Tags: process-builder

in my org i have a picklist field field_picklist(values : A,B,C) & In the process builder i wanted to execute some action 30days after a date field.

Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record? = True
Start Criteria : Created or Edited
condition is : IF field_picklist = A or field_picklist = B

Now when i create a Record with field_picklist = A the Process start properly & action is queued. But if i change value of field_picklist to B; then scheduled action in removed from queued actions list.

I thought the queued action will stay as it is....as long as criteria (field_picklist = A or field_picklist = B) is True. is it bug or am i doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is expected functionality

Comment: So is it not true that...Queued action will stay queued as long as condition is True? And it will be removed from queue when that condition becomes false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process builder will process the request as long as it satisfies the condition and as long as it is in the queue before firing that action.

When you change the condition for which the condition to put in the queue is dissatisfied then it will go out of the queue,  that is expected functionality.

As a workaround you can create a separate text field and update that field based on picklist value, first time when picklist value is A and then don't update text field with any other values. Here based on text field value you could initiate process builder's schedule action. So, it will never goes out of the queue anymore.

Comment: but in this answer https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ZgQUAA0   point 2-Time-dependent actions remain in the workflow queue only as long as the workflow rule criteria are still valid.

Comment: Till today point 2 from that link was my understanding

Comment: Also the solution you are suggesting is:- set vale of another text field to lets say 'Fire' when field_picklist = A or field_picklist = B & set it to "No Fire"  when field_picklist = C......correct?

Comment: bcoz if i don't update the Text field once it is set.....then for the condition field_picklist = C, how will process remove the queued action.?

Comment: My suggestion is, if you like to fire action always then do that based on separate text field values, since picklist value is getting changed and scheduled job will go out of queue.

Comment: Actually my logic was correct too....Its just the date used in scheduling the action was empty so it was not scheduling. Thanks for all the help!